# What's the best strategy for beating the "Welcome to the jungle" mission from the Wings of Liberty single-player campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the "Welcome to the jungle" mission, your goal is to, as Terran, collect seven canisters of a mysterious gas before the inhabiting Protos army annihilates you or seal of to many canisters. Air resistance is heavy, and the Protos are aggressive in their attacks against you and the canister sites.

**What's the best tactic for beating this level?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the difficulty you have it on and what upgrades. However, that said, everything up to hard can be beaten by just making mass marines and medics.

They key is a mobile army as you need to deny them from sealing off cansiters as well.

You need to be making constant SCVs until you have full saturation (minimum 2 SCVs per mineral patch and 3 per gas, unless you have the auto refinery). Then try to keep your money low by constantly making marines and medics. A few marauders will help as well. On insane I toss in a few goliaths to help with the void rays and scouts that they send out as well.

A few missile turrets as well as a bunker at the top of the ramp is almost enough defense to hold off any attack they send at you. If not it buys you enough time to get your army back if they are not in base.

The level also gets exponentially harder the longer you wait to gather as the protoss will have more units sent to attack as well as sealing off multiple canisters at the same time so it is in your best interest to be aggressive and grab the canisters early.

Comment: Side question: When playing single-player, is the computer "cheating" with the economy and army builds? That is, does it matter if I annihilate the Protos expansion in the east, thereby hampering my opponents economy?

Comment: Only in brutal, they mine 7 instead of 5 like normal. I actually don't know if they mine less in lower levels of difficulty.

Comment: Marine/Medic was how I beat this on the hardest difficulty level. It became much easier once I stopped trying to make goliaths. This strategy is also great for getting the feat of strength on this level. Just make sure to expand once and constantly build out marines and medics as you have time while saturating your SCVs.